# Как посчитать количество комментариев и лайков конкретного пользователя в группе через Callback API?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Хочу сделать геймификацию группы Вконтакте и пока не могу понять, как можно с помощью Callback API посчитать количество комментариев и лайков конкретного пользователя в группе. Может, кто делал подобное или скажет в каком направлении копать? В документации ничего не нашел, хотя, может быть, что плохо искал или чего не понимаю. Может, у кого-нибудь есть пример кода на php?

Comment: Плюс, надо иметь ввиду, Callback API не отправляет уведомление, если пользователь удалил репост.

Answer (score 3):

Варианта два:

**Считаем уже имеющиеся комментарии и лайки**.
В этом случае вам необходимо составлять свою базу данных: получать список комментариев и лайков к каждой записи c помощью методов [wall.getComments](https://vk.com/dev/wall.getComments) и [likes.getList](https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList), и в случае, если пользователь уже есть уже в вашем списке в базе данных, увеличивать ему счётчики. Если нет - создавать ему запись и опять же увеличивать счётчики.

**Считаем появляющиеся лайки и комментарии.**
С комментариями проблем не будет: для этого у [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api) есть уведомление `wall_reply_new`. Также создаёте базу данных, и когда вам будут приходить уведомления от ВК, просто увеличиваете счётчики у пользователей. С лайками ситуация сложнее - на новые лайки уведомлений у Callback API не предусмотрено, и вам либо придётся писать свою программу, которая будет, например, ежеминутно проверять количество лайков на стене и формировать ваш список, либо самостоятельно каждый раз подсчитывать это количество. Других вариантов пока нет.